# Why is there a huge discrepancy between the adjusted close and the close stock of this stock (ENDV)?

Tags: stocks, stock-split

I have just noticed that back in October 2015, the ENDV stock was worth something around 80-100 dollars according to its adjusted close price (i.e. the one that google and yahoo finance show). However the not adjusted close price was around 0.08-0.1. A difference in the order of a thousand! What is the cause for that?

Today's price of the stock is 0.017, in terms of order of magnitude, similar to the not-adjusted price back in 2015. If I had 100 dollar in 2015 in the company, would I have now 0.017 dollars or is there something am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have just notice that back in October 2015, the ENDV stock was worth something around 80-100 dollars according to its adjusted close price (i.e. the one that google and yahoo finance show). However the not adjusted close price was around 0.08-0.1. A hundredth factor difference! What is the cause for that?

Endonovo Therapeutics Inc.'s (ENDV) valuation has come off massively since 2015. It looks like the treatments they were developing did not pan out. Back in 2015, its market capitalization (market cap) was in the order of tens of billions of dollars for a while. Now the company's market cap appears to be slightly more than 1 million dollars. As you might know, huge changes in stock prices in either direction, even within just a few months of time, are not uncommon in the biotech industry.

ENDV's actual (raw) price has never been around or close to $100 per share. The maximum it actually has ever traded was $5.3 per share back in June 2014. The $100 per share price you see for October 2015 through Google Finance or Yahoo Finance is due to the backward adjustment in the prices of the stock from a [1:1000 reverse stock split from December 2019](https://www.stocksplithistory.com/?symbol=ENDV). That is, the actual stock price fell so much towards the end of 2019, to as low as $0.002 per share, that the company had to do a reverse stock split. So the $100 per share stock price you see now for October 2015 was actually $0.1 ($100/1000) per share at the time.

The historic share prices you see in Google or Yahoo finance are already adjusted for stock splits unless otherwise stated. The historic "adjusted" prices on such websites are usually adjusted extra only for the dividends in addition to the stock splits.

> Today's price of the stock is 0.017, in terms of order of magnitude, similar to the the the not-adjusted price. If I had 100 dollar in 2015 in the company would I have now 0.017 dollars or is there something am I missing?

Yes, you would have lost 99.98% of your money ($0.017/$100 - 1) if you had purchased the corresponding number of shares of ENDV stock back in October 2015 for $100. If there were no reverse stock split, the stock price, ceteris paribus, would be $0.000017 now ($0.017/1000).

Answer (score 0):

The factor is a thousandth not a hundredth.

In 2019, ENDV did a 1-for-1,000 reverse stock split of its common shares.

Every 1,000 shares of the Company's issued and outstanding common stock were combined into one issued and outstanding share of common